# PHP get value with file_get_content()

Tags: php, file-get-contents

i want to get of " file " m3u8 from this page " view-source:http://www.freelivestream.tv/embedPlayer.php?file=cartoon "

i'm trying this code but not getting all value it give , any help please

```
    <?php

$url = "http://www.freelivestream.tv/embedPlayer.php?file=cartoon";
$contents = file_get_contents($url);

preg_match('@m3u8([^"]+)@',$contents,$filo);
$filo = urldecode($filo[0]);



echo $filo;


?>
```

i'm want to get like this : http://95.141.32.136:8081/edge/cartoon/playlist.m3u8?wmsAuthSign=c2VydmVyX3RpbWU9OS8xOS8yMDE3IDEyOjE4OjEyIFBNJmhhc2hfdmFsdWU9aGI4bVZBZEdKY3E3ZVpFOWx3REdadz09JnZhbGlkbWludXRlcz01

but with my code it give only : m3u8?wmsAuthSign=c2VydmVyX3RpbWU9OS8xOS8yMDE3IDEyOjE4OjEyIFBNJmhhc2hfdmFsdWU9aGI4bVZBZEdKY3E3ZVpFOWx3REdadz09JnZhbGlkbWludXRlcz01

thanks

Comment: Use this code then explode & use it <?php $url = "http://www.freelivestream.tv/embedPlayer.php?file=cartoon";
 $contents = file_get_contents($url);
preg_match('@file:(.*)@',$contents,$filo);
$filo = urldecode($filo[0]);



echo $filo;?>

Answer (score 0):

Use below code:

```
$url = "http://www.freelivestream.tv/embedPlayer.php?file=cartoon";
$contents = file_get_contents($url);

preg_match('/"(.*)m3u8(.*)"/',$contents,$filo);
$filo = urldecode($filo[0]);

echo $filo;
```

Hope this will help.